# Two columns DataGrid: Property name and Property value

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpfdatagrid

I have a `Settings` class like this:

```
public class Settings {
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}
```

I might have the following instance:

```
new Settings {
    Foo = "xxx",
    Bar = 20
}
```

and I'd like to show that class in a DataGrid like this:

```
--------------------
| Settings | Value |
--------------------
|   Foo    |  xxx  |
|   Bar    |  20   |
```

What would be a proper way of doing it? I know I could create some temporarily class (with two properties), and using reflection create as many instances of that class as properties in `Settings`, but I perhaps there is a cleaner way of doing it, taking advantages of bindings (two way), etc.

I'm using WPF + MVVM.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just showing a single class instance like this, it would be better to not use a `DataGrid`.  Just build a custom `DataTemplate` for your class to display it how you choose based on a 2x3 grid.

Answer (score -1):

You can bind the class into the DataGrid.

First you have to Bind the property to a column in the DataGrid.

```
<DataGrid Name="dtgSettings" Height="200">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Foo" Width="150" Binding="{Binding Foo}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Bar" Width="150" Binding="{Binding Bar}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

After that its just add the new Settings dinamically.

```
dtgSettings.Items.Add( new Settings
{
    Foo = "Foo",
    Bar = 0,
};
```